# Keyboard layout for (learning to / switching) hands

Tags: accessibility, keyboard, smartphone, keyboard-layout

I would like to know, if keyboards had songs for flipping the keyboard along the vertical axis of the phone's display, than would that happen someone who wanted to learn how to key in or swipe keys with their other hand, in case they lost one hand or arm and just wanted to try it?

Thanks.

Comment: 'With their other hand' assumes everyone types with one hand? I barely know anyone who does this.

Comment: I have been using the Nuance Swype keyboard and use it with one thumb. It is very fast (even faster than topping with two hands on a normal keyboard in my opinion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flipping the keyboard is unlikely to be advantageous to someone forced to use their left hand.

It's your brain that locates the keys to be pressed and coordinates your hand and finger into position. This has nothing to do with whether you are left or right handed or are forced, in some other way, to use your less dominant hand.

If you pass your phone to your less dominant hand and attempt to type a 'Q' you will still automatically reach for the top left area of the keyboard because that is where you have learned to find the 'Q'.

The only effect that flipping a keyboard will have is that you will have to re-learn the locations of the keys and practice for a long time in order to be able to type at normal speed.

If you want to experience the amount of disorientation changing the keyboard layout gives, try switching to a 'Dvorak' layout and see how long it takes you to get up to normal speed.